# Setting multiple controllers in one state, IONIC

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, routes

I want to check if there is a user signed in, for it to redirect to another page, if there is no user, i want to redirect to the homePage. The home page has a controller called storeCtrl.

I tried this:

```
    .state('homePage', 
    {
      url: '/homePage',
      templateUrl: 'templates/homePage/homePage.html',
      controller:'storeCtrl',
       function ($localStorage,$state) {
        if ($localStorage.user) {
          $state.go('tabs.profile');
          } else {
            $state.go('homePage');
          }
      }
```

})

but it doesn't work. I tried this also:

```
    .state('homePage', 
    {
      url: '/homePage',
      templateUrl: 'templates/homePage/homePage.html',
      controller:
       function ($localStorage,$state) {
        if ($localStorage.user) {
          $state.go('tabs.profile');
          } else {
            $state.go('homePage'),
            controller:storeCtrl

          }
      }
```

})

but that also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

instead of putting it in the state. try to add this inside **app.run**

```
app.run(function($ionicPlatform,$state,$rootScope,$localStorage) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
     //your code
  })
      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event,next, nextParams, fromState,fromParams) {
      var nextScreen=next.name;
      if (nextScreen!="homePage" && $localStorage.user===undefined) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go('homePage');
        return;
      } 
    });
})
```

Comment: that throws a RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    error

Comment: Maximum call stack size will come only if there is a loop .. that is if the everytime on root change it is going inside the if block. Try doing some debuggin. Also i added a return after state.go

Comment: i tried that, it doesn't return an error but it doesnt work. I signed in and the user was saved, but when I refreshed the page, even the the user is still saved it still redirects to the homepage instead of the profile page

Comment: the $localStrage.user===undefined is return true that means. The reason might be it was not loaded or comparing it with undefined is not the right way. You can try different things, eg  nextScreen!="homePage"  && $localStorage.user